# Mac assertion failure using both JavaFX and Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

First of all: no, I am not trying to embed JavaFX panel inside a JPanel.

I have an application in JavaFX but I need to use a JFrame.
As far as I understand, they can coexist, but I am getting an error (Assertion Failure).
I am getting:
[image: bug screenshot]

Arrows shows:

1. JFrame opens
2. Java version == 1.7.0_71
3. Error

The code to reproduce is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
            f.setVisible(true);
        }});

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("TEST");
    App.launch(args);
}
```

If I remove the Thread.sleep(), I get no error, but my JavaFX App does not start.
If I keep the Thread.sleep(), I get the error.
If I remove the invokeLater(), I get a HeadlessException

I cannot move to Java 8.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Unfortunately the post does not work for me. Option 1 does not work anymore; option 2 is not my application; option 3 is kind of crazy; option 4 not my application.

Comment: System.setProperty("javafx.macosx.embedded", "true"); Did the trick!